# Sequences (Analysis) Writing $U_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can any one help me to solve this 
$$
U_{n+1}=5U_n-6U_{n-1}
$$

$$
U_0=1,U_1=4
$$
$$
V_n=U_{n+1}-2U_n
$$
I've proved that $V_n$ is a geometric sequence and I managed to write $V_n$ by $n$ 
$$ 
V_n=2.3^n
$$
How can I write $U_n$ formula by $n$?
If any one can help me I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Call
$$U_{n+1}=\lambda^n$$

and get

$$\lambda^2-5\lambda+6=0$$

conclude that

$$U_n=a\cdot2^n+b\cdot3^n$$

and find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks, but how did u get that $U_n=a.2ⁿ+b.3ⁿ$

Comment: Intact I just couldn't figure out what It done , Thanks anyway :)

Comment: See that $\lambda=2$ or $\lambda=3$ and its linear combination also fit the recurrence.